# c# One public Streamreader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I' don't know much about C#.I'm trying to create a program that can calculate results for running competitions. I have created two methods: DoStuff(), with which I set up a Datagridview table columns and displays a text file splitted.And Method- Sorter(), with which I sort the runners into groups and display them in to the List boxes.

**My problem.**
Every time when i try to debug a program i get a following error:

> 'Cannot read from a closed TextReader.'

As you can see i set the StreamReader as public. But those two methods can not access it.
Is it possible in some way like this to use one StreamReader?!
Or i have to write my code in Form-Load and then it is the only way to access it?
My Code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\result.txt");
    public string line;
    public  List<string> V = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> V12 = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> V14 = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> V18 = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> V50 = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> VB = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> VC = new List<string>();

    public  List<string> S = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> S12 = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> S14 = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> S18 = new List<string>();
    public  List<string> S40 = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public void ReadFile()
    {
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SORTER();
        Dostuff();         
    }


    public void Dostuff()
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\result.txt"))
            return;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
         dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Number";
          dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "name";
           dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "time";

        using (sr)
            while (sr.Peek() > -1 )
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(';'));                    
            }            
    }

    public void SORTER()
    {
        using (sr)
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(";V;")) { V.Add(line); }
                else if (line.Contains(";V12;")) { V12.Add(line); }
                else if (line.Contains(";V14;")) { V14.Add(line); }
                else if (line.Contains(";V18;")) { V18.Add(line); }
                else if (line.Contains(";V50;")) { V50.Add(line); }

                else if (line.Contains(";S12;")) { S12.Add(line); }
                else if (line.Contains(";S14;")) { S14.Add(line); }
                else if (line.Contains(";S18;")) { S18.Add(line); }
                else if (line.Contains(";S40;")) { S40.Add(line); }
                if (line.Contains(";S;")) { S.Add(line); }
            }

        listBox1.DataSource = V12;
        listBox2.DataSource = V50;
        listBox3.DataSource = V;
        listBox4.DataSource = S;
        listBox5.DataSource = S18;
        listBox6.DataSource = S40;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lesson 1: format your code nicely. It's much easier to spot errors if the indentation is correct and empty lines are removed where they do not add logical semantics. (@Amy did that for you now)

Comment: Lesson 2: each time you write `using`, the object that is being used gets destroyed afterwards. You do that twice for `sr`, so it will work the first time and *not* the second time.

Comment: `using (sr)`.  You're disposing of your reader here.

Comment: you don't have to make sr to be public placeholder you could declare one within the using statement

Comment: first question: why not just open the stream whenever you need to and close it when you are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this inside your Form definition:

```
public StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\result.txt");
```

That opens your file once when your form is created and leaves it open. Doing that can block or crash your application if you get an IO error, and often causes “file is in use” errors. You should open a file only when you actually need to use it, then close it immediately after. Wherever you do:

```
using (sr)
```

you should instead be doing this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\result.txt"))
```

Actually, you should be doing this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "result.txt")))
```

Comment: You need to assign thoes new stream readers to a variable in the using

Comment: Correct you are, @Scott.

Answer (score 0):

You have your StreamReader in a using block in your SORTER() method.  This means after that block ends, the StreamReader will be disposed.  When you try to reuse the same StreamReader in your DoStuff() method, you will get the error you described, as that StreamReader is no longer in a state to be read from.

Instead of having a global variable for your StreamReader, you could create these as local variables in each of your methods.